# Azure connection string best practices

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, connection-string, application-settings, staging

I have an application that I am just migrating to Azure. Currently I use web.config transformation to manage changing the database connecting string dev/staging/prod environments. How is it best to manage these multiple connection strings in Azure?

Comment: No answer includes Azure Key Vault which definitely should be mentioned here to secure your credentials (or an encryption key) for said credentials. What is interesting is that you can register your Azure app with the Key Vault directly and do not need to use any credentials for your keyVault Client while being sure that the only one to be able to read your connection strings (or relevent encryption keys) is the app itself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In cases where it doesn't matter if the developer can see production credentials, you can use the built-in Visual Studio 10 config transformations.  If this is what you're looking for, follow these steps:

1.Navigate to your Azure project folder in file explorer
2. Make a copy of ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
3. Rename copy to ServiceConfiguration.Base.cscfg
4. For each build configuration (e.g. Dev, Staging, Production), create a ServiceConfiguration.<build config name>.cscfg file.  In these files, you can use the normal [config transformation syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)
5. Open your .ccproj file in a text editor
6. Find the following node,

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ServiceDefinition Include="ServiceDefinition.csdef" />
    <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and replace it with this (you will have to edit this block to match your build configs):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ServiceDefinition Include="ServiceDefinition.csdef" />
    <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" />
    <None Include="ServiceConfiguration.Base.cscfg">
        <DependentUpon>ServiceConfiguration.cscfg</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="ServiceConfiguration.Dev.cscfg">
        <DependentUpon>ServiceConfiguration.cscfg</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="ServiceConfiguration.Staging.cscfg">
        <DependentUpon>ServiceConfiguration.cscfg</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="ServiceConfiguration.Production.cscfg">
        <DependentUpon>ServiceConfiguration.cscfg</DependentUpon>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

7.Add the following at the end of the .ccproj file, just above `</Project>`:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="ServiceConfiguration.Base.cscfg" Transform="ServiceConfiguration.$(Configuration).cscfg" Destination="ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" />
</Target>
```

8.If you're using a CI server that doesn't have Visual Studio 10 installed, you'll probably have to copy the C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web folder and its contents from a development machine to the server.

**Update:** As @SolarSteve [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190984/azure-connection-string-best-practices/6187519#6187519), you might have to add a namespace to your ServiceConfiguration.*.cscfg files.  Here's an example of ServiceConfiguration.Base.cscfg:

```
<sc:ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyServiceName" osFamily="1" osVersion="*" xmlns:sc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sc:Role name="MyRoleName">
    <sc:Instances count="1" />
    <sc:ConfigurationSettings>
      <sc:Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="xxx" />
    </sc:ConfigurationSettings>
  </sc:Role>
</sc:ServiceConfiguration>
```

Comment: I get a "WAT020: Only one service definition can be active." error when building using the above... any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Hey jmac, I've created a VS addin (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) which uses TransformXml a bunch of ppl asked for Azure project support. This looks like it would be a good starting point for me. If I implement it can u ensure I got it right? You can contact me by email: sayedha [at] {MICROSOFTdotCOM}.

Answer (score 14):

Personally we:

1. Dropped web config transformations completely.
2. Setting is retrieved from cscfg.
3. Development version of cscfg points to local development environment (that's stored in version control).
4. While deploying to production, we supply secure credentials for production SQL Azure and storage.

For sample of the settings management class that scans application settings and cloud environment for configuration values, you can check out open source [Lokad.CQRS for Windows Azure](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cqrs/) project (see CloudSettingsProvider)

Answer (score 7):

You can use CloudConfigurationManager in Azure SDK 1.7 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager

This starts by looking in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg e.g. ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg for config setting. If it isn't there it falls back to web.config and app.config

For example

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")
```

Will look in the appropriate cscfgfile for StorageConnectionString setting, then it will search the web.config and then app.config.

Answer (score 6):

We have a number of environments (local dev inside dev fabric, local dev outside dev fabric, testing, release which has 2 versions: release/prod and release/staging and 20 projects some of which need some variability in configure settings. We solved this problem by creating a tiny "config" project, included subfolders there that match the environments. We copy files from the subfolder depending on which build we're doing into root folder of the config project, during every compile.

All other projects link to the config project for .config files.  We also use partial config files to keep the insanity of repeating the same info all the time across various environments.

Hope this helps

Comment: Finally published a blog on this at http://www.paraleap.com/blog/post/Managing-environments-in-a-distributed-Azure-or-other-cloud-based-NET-solution.aspx

Comment: If all of your solutions reuse the same configuration project, how do you handle solution-specific configuration properties?

Comment: If all your your solutions share the same config files and *SolutionA* needs an extra config property (i.e. `<Setting name="NewSettingProperty" value="123" />`, how do you give that to *SolutionA* without also giving it to every other solution?

Comment: You can create subfolders in the Config project to segregate different projects from one another, if I understood you correctly

Answer (score 6):

I had the same requirement for transforming ServiceConfiguration.

I went with the answer from jmac (thank you!), but had trouble with the namespace in the Base version:

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="TestCloud2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="1" osVersion="*">
```

after a bit more poking around found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062636/how-to-apply-vs2010-web-config-transformation-to-an-element-with-a-namespace-attr) by Andrew Patterson (Thank You).

so my resulting transform file:

```
<asc:ServiceConfiguration serviceName="TestCloud2" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns:asc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="1" osVersion="*">
<asc:Role name="WebRole1">
    <asc:Instances count="1" />
    <asc:ConfigurationSettings>
        <asc:Setting name="LoggingStorage" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </asc:ConfigurationSettings>
</asc:Role>
```