# Windows Azure Connection Strings - How to Handle Local vs. Production?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-configuration

I'm in the process of deploying some windows azure projects and I've noticed that it's a bit of a pain to constantly switch my role configuration settings from using LocalStorage to actually use my Windows Azure Storage connection strings.

For local development, I want to use this:

```
UseDevelopmentStorage=true
```

But for deployed apps, I want to use something like:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=blah
```

I end up either changing my role's configuration connection strings just before I deploy, or if I forget to do that, I'll attempt to go into the Windows Azure portal and change them (but that usually happens after I watch my role instances start and stop over and over).

I feel like I'm missing something basic, but is there a straight-forward way to have the deployment process switch my role connection settings to use the production storage accounts instead of local storage?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190984/azure-connection-string-best-practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered a similar question here:

[Visual Studio 2010 can apply Debug or Release transformations to Web.config, but what about the Azure settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224040/visual-studio-2010-can-apply-debug-or-release-transformations-to-web-config-but/4226683#4226683)

Answer (score 4):

You can use CloudConfigurationManager in Azure SDK 1.7 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager

This starts by looking in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg e.g. ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg for config setting. If it isn't there it falls back to web.config and app.config

For example

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")
```

Will look in the appropriate cscfg file for StorageConnectionString setting, then it will search the web.config and then app.config.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Visual Studio config transformations, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190984/azure-connection-string-best-practices/5185380#5185380) to the question Panagiotis mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

[Switching from one connectionstring to another when moving from development to cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125610/switching-from-one-connectionstring-to-another-when-moving-from-development-to-cl/5133192#5133192)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use CI server you can change the connection string there automatically. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125610/switching-from-one-connectionstring-to-another-when-moving-from-development-to-cl/5125996#5125996).