# Running my HttpApplication in my own AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain, httpapplication

I'm looking for a way to run my HttpApplication in an AppDomain I created myself programmatically.

as the **AppManagerAppDomainFactory** is a sealed class, I wondered if there was a way to implement my own IAppManagerAppDomainFactory without having to patch IIS.

If you're interested and want to know more [I suggest this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/iis/ASPNETInternalsIISAndTheProcessModel2.aspx)

Thanks for your suggestions (even if I don't think I'll get a acceptable answer ^^)

Comment: Why?  Are you trying to run 2 web apps in the same process but different app domains?

Comment: Yes, it's one of the my 2 goals. The other one is explained in that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734776/azure-web-config-per-environment/6676439#6676439