# Windows Azure - Virtual Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, web-config

I have one web application and virtual application in Azure.  They are separate projects in VS2010 and I have added them to one solution with one Azure deployment project.

I have created multiple web.configs to control parameters, ie web.debug.config etc.

When I publish to azure I specify debug which works for the main application but the virtual application is pointing to the web.config not the variants.  How do I correct this please?

Many Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The solution that worked for me from http://blog.hill-it.be/2011/03/07/no-web-config-transformation-in-local-azure/:

> To fix this, unload your Azure project, open the project file for edit and add the tag *[under the corresponding PropertyGroup]*:
>
> ```
> <Project ...>    
>     <PropertyGroup>
>       ...
>           <packagewebrole>true</packagewebrole>
> ```

### Workaround

There's also a workaround, it will work for a local development, but not for continuous integration (or at least you will have to find another trick).

1. In your service definition file add a new Site section:

> ```
> <Site name="AnotherSite" physicalDirectory="c:\AnotherSite">
>   <Bindings>
>     <Binding name="APIEndpoint" endpointName="AnotherSiteEndpoint" />
>   </Bindings>
> </Site>
> ```

1. Add a new endpoint to match the code above (any port works):

> ```
> <InputEndpoint name="AnotherSiteEndpoint" protocol="http" port="623" />
> ```

1. Go to your *web-project --> right-click --> Publish... --> FTP --> Location = "c:\AnotherSite"*
2. Press F5 and go to http://127.0.0.1:623

It should work.

Comment: Thanks Nikita.  Was on my phone the other day and couldn't comment but was allowed to mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

Web application always uses `web.config`. If you want to use debug / release versions you have to create web.config [`Transformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). In this case web.config is transformed at build time using selected build target.

Comment: I have created the transformations but it is ignored for the virtual app, the main app does pay attention ot the build target.  Thanks for replying though.