# Azure set hostHeader according to project configuration

Tags: azure, azure-configuration, azure-deployment

hostHeader can be set in ServiceDefinition.csdef file as

```xml
<Site name="Web">        
  <Bindings>
    <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.mysite.com"/>          
  </Bindings>
</Site>
```

How can I change this setting according to my project configuration?

e.g. when my project is published in debug mode, hosetHeader should be set to `test.mysite.com`,
and when project is published in release mode, hostHeader should be set to `www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Visual Studio 10 config transformations.  To get transformations working with Azure configs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190984/azure-connection-string-best-practices/5185380#5185380).

Comment: I followed the steps you mentioned in the link. When I try to publish, I get a warning `ServiceDefinition.Staging.csdef(2,2): warning : No element in the source document matches '/ServiceDefinition'` . What could be the problem?

Comment: @ajay_whiz  I recently ran into this problem with our ServiceDefinition.csdef tranformation.  To resolve it, I added a sd namespace to the ServiceDefinition node:  

<sd:ServiceDefinition name="name" xmlns:sd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
...
      <sd:Site name="Web">
        <sd:Bindings>
          <sd:Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" hostHeader="www.site.com" />
        </sd:Bindings>
      </sd:Site>
...
</sd:ServiceDefinition>

Comment: it worked!! I checked in RoleModel.xml file in package file it is correctly set as expected. Thanks

Comment: @ajay_whiz Cool!  Happy transforming. ;-)