# new relic change application name at run time .NET

Tags: .net, windows, azure, newrelic

I am setting up new relic monitoring in our product and want to change the application name of the application at start up.

The reason for this is our product is in windows azure and we have 4 env that we host the product in. When we do a deploy we pick the configuration file that we are using and that is how how we deploy to the different env's. The other part of the problem is that product has 9 azure roles and we want to monitor them separate from each other so they all have different names. So if we have 9 roles and 4 env's with at least 2 servers each it gets hard to know what env/role is having problems.

What I want to do is when the role starts up I want to add the env's name to the application name.

Any ideas on how to do this?

From what I can tell there are at least two places to set the application name is in the newrelic.xml and the other is in the app.config/web.config, and I am not sure which is more important then the other.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for multiple apps, you want to use web.config files.  Newrelic.xml will only roll-up the apps to a single entry.  You might try something like web.config transforms.  There are multiple ways to do this, but check this SO post here: [Azure connection string best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190984/azure-connection-string-best-practices/5185380#5185380)